# Why same code is twice slower when migrated from VS2010 to VS2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl, visual-studio-2015

I recently ported some legacy code from Visual Studio 2010 32bits to Visual Studio 2015 64bits.

My CPPUNIT tests speed time (in Debug mode) was multiplied by more than two. I was really surprised so I tried to isolate and reproduce the problem on smaller piece of code:

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

class Message
{
public:
    Message(const std::string &shortDescription)
        : m_shortDescription(shortDescription)
    {
        m_details.push_back( shortDescription );
    }

    inline const std::string& str() const { return m_shortDescription; }

private:
    std::string m_shortDescription;

    typedef std::deque<std::string> Details;
    Details m_details;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::cout << sizeof(size_t) << std::endl;
    clock_t started = clock();
    std::string str;
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 1000000; ++i)
    {
        Message msg("foo");
    }

    std::cout << static_cast<double>(clock()-started)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "secs" << std::endl;

    std::cin >> str;

    return 0;
}
```

This basic program performance drops dramatically when compiled in Debug mode with Visual Studio 2015 (x64 or x86):

- Visual Studio 2010, Debug, x64: ~10s
- Visual Studio 2010, Debug, x86: ~10s
- Visual Studio 2015, Debug, x64: ~20s
- Visual Studio 2015, Debug, x86: ~20s

In Release, VS2015 generates faster code:

- Visual Studio 2010, Release, x64: ~1.3s
- Visual Studio 2010, Release, x86: ~1.3s
- Visual Studio 2015, Release, x64: ~0.2s
- Visual Studio 2015, Release, x86: ~0.2s

How could make Visual Studio Debug code so slow? Did they extend _DEBUG check on STL containers (`std::deque::push_back` is the only piece of code relevantly using CPU here)?

Comment: This is normal. The debug version is not optimized and is doing additional work. 2015 has added additional features to debug mode, so more work is done.

Comment: Two times more work to do....isn't that excessive? No way this extra checking can be deactivated?

Comment: Since, you will be deploying the Release version anyway, why do you care about the speed of Debug version? And if you are deploying Debug versions - you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes, it looks excessive. But we do not know what happens behind scenes. Take the bright side: the release version is much faster. I have a slow computer an I have also noticed that sometimes 2015 appears very slow, but I did not have the  curiosity to test the speed.

Comment: Unless someone from the VC++ compiler pops along I doubt we will have much of an answer. The only thing I can suggest is to look at the two disassemblies side by side to see the difference yourself. BTW are the debug timings done with an attached debugger (I presume not but sometime the obvious question isn't asked)?

Comment: You perform memory allocation due to the push_back, so they probably beefed up the memory management part of the debug libs. This is a good thing, because memory corruption is real PITA in c++.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Thanks all for the help. I won't deploy Debug version, but I often work/test with this mode and it's a pain to have such a slow execution (my concern as a developer, not end user concern).

Comment: @Dennis: Tested without debugger attached, with it attached it's getting even worst (not surprising).

Comment: @ZDF: You may post this as an answer, I think it makes sense to accept it.

Comment: You can turn off debugging options you don't need.

Comment: _"I think it makes sense to accept it"_ It's fine, I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: Another hint: they might changed something with std::string, as it is not copy on write in debug (at least in VS2013) ...

Comment: @ChrisG: MSVC++ hasn't had a refcounted/copy-on-write `std::string` implementation (debug or release) since VS.NET 2001 I think.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You are correct. Sorry, I was misinformed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has increase the level of validation that is performed on containers and iterators pretty much with each major release of MSVC++.

You can reduce the time that debug runs take by disabling some of that validation.  For example, add the following to the top of the source file:

```
#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0
```

Note that the above configuration macro will also reduce the VS2010 debug runtime as well, I suspect.

See the following docs for some details:

- [`_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697468.aspx)
- [Debug Iterator Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982.aspx)
- [Checked Iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965.aspx)

In general, I'd suggest leaving iterator debugging enabled unless the runtime hit is unbearable.  It's immensely helpful in preventing using iterators incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll try that, but as you said, just to check, because I prefer to keep iterator debugging enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely optimization. There is one well-known change you can make - the others you could experiment with and decide what's OK in a debug build. (Optimizations can make it hard to step.)

In your project properties config set C/C++->Code Generation->Basic Runtime Checks to Default.

Your code's x86 Debug time went from about 17s down to 9s with just that one change.

I only had VS 2013 handy to test, but the same thing happens in VS 2015.

Compare the generated code or read about it in [this blog post](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/visual-c-debug-buildsfast-checks-cause-5x-slowdowns/).